# Как правильно работать с несколькими панелями в Windows Forms и WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Собственно, давно задался этим вопросом, но ответ найти не смог.
Если на одной форме нужно, чтобы на одном и том же месте отображались различные панели (типа как `TabControl` без визуализируемых табов), как это следует **грамотно** реализовывать? Интересуют грамотные реализации на **WinForms** и **WPF**.

---

До этого использовал только в WinForms в следующих вариациях:

Скачивал с нета пользовательский элемент управления, наследованный от tabcontrol, в котором перехватывалось какое-то событие, и вкладки не визуализировались. В дальнейшем переключение вкладок велось через иные элементы управления.

Накладывал друг на друга панели, и периодически менял у них визибилити. Гемор ещё тот.

Answer (score 6):

Насчёт WinForms не скажу, а для WPF есть, как правильно отмечает [@Spawn](/users/12111/spawn), миллион разных решений, от переключения видимости до рестайлинга `ItemsControl`'а. Выберите то, которое подходит лучше к *семантике* вашей задачи.

Я, например, часто пользуюсь таким решением: определяю просто

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding VM}"/>
```

и подменяю VM, когда нужно. Отображение VM задаётся, понятно, через `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Нравится ваш вариант с Binding VM, буду пробовать)

Comment: А как это грамотно сделать? Я например предполагаю, что нужно все отдельные мне "панели" определить в различных xaml файлах, возможно в виде Page, а потом каким-то образом подключить их к главному окну в этот самый Binding, вот только как это сделать?

Comment: @svinopapka: нужные панели надо определить в `DataTemplate`'ах для того типа VM (то есть, объекта вашей бизнес-логики), который они будут представлять. Они подключаются обычно в глобальные ресурсы.

Answer (score 2):

"Правильного" решения в таком вопросе, пожалуй, нет. Мне кажется, что в каждом конкретном случае будут свои нюансы.

Для WinForms посмотрите, например, такой [пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31770/Wizard-Form-Implementation).

А для WPF есть [такое](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard) более ли менее стандартное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, но меня больше интересуют не визарды, а просто переключение между панелями, которые могут быть вообще между собой никак не связаны.

Comment: Это и будет тогда просто переключением :-)

Answer (score 1):

Рассскажу, как делал это когда-то для WinForms. Сразу предупрежу, что это все то же переключение *visibility* у n-ного количества панелей, наложенных друг на друга. В качестве переключателей используются RadioButton'ы. Каждый RadioButton знает, какую панель он должен показать (можно, например, сохранить ссылку на необходимую панель в свойство Tag). Также сохранена ссылка на панель, которая показывается в текущий момент. Тогда примерный код обработчика  радиокнопки будет таким:

```
private Panel selectedPanel;  // Ссылка на активную панель

...

private void SelectPanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
    if (radioButton != null && radioButton.Checked)
    {
        if (selectedPanel != null)
            selectedPanel.Hide();

        selectedPanel = radioButton.Tag as Panel;

        if (selectedPanel != null)
            selectedPanel.Show();
    }
}
```

По-моему, не такой уж и гемор, если учесть, что больше кода не нужно. Но есть неудобство при работе с этой "стопкой" панелей в дизайнере форм.

Comment: С какой-то стороны действительно просто, но в целом, т.к. работа ведётся исключительно в визуальном редакторе - вообще не катит)

Answer (score 1):

Насчет winForms - есть такая штука как GroupBox, и скрыв ее - скроешь все дочерние элементы, как по мне самое оно.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте WPF `Navigation`. Создаете страницы `Page`. Переключаете их в `Frame`.
 Вот примеры:
 [Page + Frame](https://habrahabr.ru/post/140749/) 
 
[DialogWizard из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972123(v=vs.85).aspx)